$A,B \in GL_{n}$. Let $f(x) = det(xA+(1-x)B)$. Then conclude $f$ is a non constant polynomial.
The Actual Question
$A,B \in GL_{n}$. Let $f(x) = det(xA+(1-x)B)$. Then conclude $f=0$ has finitely many solutions.
Thoughts
I understand that $f$ is a non zero polynomial, and if it's not a constant polynomial, it has indeed finitely many roots. But suppose, $A = B$, then $f = det(B) \ne 0$. Thus, $f = 0$ has no solution. So, I also need to show that why in other cases $(A \ne B)$, $f$ is a non constant polynomial.

I tried that, that gave f(0) = det(B) and f(1) = det(A), but what if det(A) = det(B), so there a possibility that f is a constant polynomial, how to rule that out?

Note that when $x\ne0$, $\det(xA+(1-x)B)=x^n\det(A)\det\left(I-\frac{1-x}{x}A^{-1}B\right)$.

If $f$ is a constant polynomial, it is a non-zero constant polynomial (since $A$ and $B$ are assumed to be invertible). I think the question is conceived in such a way that "zero solutions" is also a case of "finitely many". If, on the other hand, $f$ is a non-constant polynomial, it has only finitely many zeroes.

It is clear that $x=0$ is not a solution since $B \in \mathsf{GL}_n$. $\def\det{\operatorname{det}} \det(xA+(1-x)B)=(-1)^n x^n \det B \det(B^{-1}(B-A)-x^{-1}I)$. Set $\lambda=x^{-1}$ and you have the eigenvalue equation for $B^{-1}(B-A)=I-B^{-1}A \in \mathsf{GL}_n$ and therefore there are $n$ solutions for $x$.
